# App Freezes with 'Can't do regex matching on object 1'

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data

My iPad app just freezes then throws the following error in the debugger.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object 1.'
```

Performing a Google search results in answers involving Core Data, but none really illustrate how to find out why this error occurs.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What code? I have 20+ Objects in Core Data and storing 50k records. I have over 18k lines of code?

Comment: what is object 1? you are calling regex on it, and THAT is related code.

Answer (score 6):

The issue was a Predicate on a BOOL.

```
@"(thing LIKE [c] %@)  OR (thing == nil)"
```

Fixed with

```
@"(synced == 0) OR (synced == nil)"
```

Works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to execute a predicate doing a regexp matching on a property that is not an `NSString` (likely a number with value `1`).

Try debugging your app and break on exceptions (see http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), it will stop your app when the exception is met.